# Strange zero estimate from quantile regression (quantreg.rq)

Tags: r, quantile-regression

I'm using this package to do a simple quantile regression. I have a dataset with 70 observations, a non-normal outcome called "post_tx_los" (length of hospital stay following organ transplant), and a continuous variable called PMI which is a muscle measurement. I'm getting some weird results for this analysis - for some reason, the model estimate comes out at exactly 0 with a pvalue of 1.0 -

> summary(rq(post_tx_los~PMI,data=heart_muscle),se='nid')

```
Call: rq(formula = post_tx_los ~ PMI, data = heart_muscle)

tau: [1] 0.5

Coefficients:
        Value    Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 16.00000  5.99368    2.66948  0.00949
PMI          0.00000  0.78378    0.00000  1.00000
```

It was suggested to me to try running it again after removing a few observations. When I removed one it was the same, but after removing two everything looks much different (and sensical):

> summary(rq(post_tx_los~PMI,data=heart_muscle68),se='nid')

```
Call: rq(formula = post_tx_los ~ PMI, data = heart_muscle68)

tau: [1] 0.5

Coefficients:
        Value    Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 10.00527  6.60840    1.51402  0.13479
PMI          0.96677  0.94047    1.02796  0.30772
```

Looking at the two observations that were removed in the second analysis, nothing particularly strange stood out about them. The LOS variable has mean 23.3, median 16.0, range 1-107. The PMI variable has mean 5.8, median 5.5, range 1.5-11.8. For those two observations, the LOS values were (8,33) and the PMI values were (7.6, 3.7).

Do you have any insight onto why I might be getting this estimate of exactly zero in my first analysis? It doesn't really make sense after noting how dramatically it changes when simply removing two observations.

I did also run these models in SAS (PROC QUANTREG) and got similar results.

added images:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqO2O.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/efmnE.png]

edit:

BTW here is Roger Koenker's (he wrote the package) response:

"rq is trying to find a basic solution to fit exactly p points (2 in your case) if LOS is
in days, and you have several observation pairs with the same LOS and different
PMI then it is possible to get an exact fit to two of such pairs and get zero as the
estimated coefficient.  Discrete response is rather problematic for QR inference
since it really relies on the response having a conditional density.  The usual
treatment for such problems is to dither() the data to perturb the response.  After
all people don’t really stay 3 days, they stay 3.13 days or something like that.
See ?dither in the quantreg package for further details."

Comment: I'd post the data so we can check and plot graph(s),  but in essence you're being told (a) there is no detectable relationship (b) the median of the response is 16. This may be puzzling but it doesn't sound absurd. Deleting observations requires a stronger reason than not believing or not trusting the initial result

Comment: I had sent this to a biostat prof I worked with and he suggested that as a first step. Don't you think it's strange that the estimate for PMI would be EXACTLY zero like that? And that it would change so much after just removing two observations?

Comment: I added two images, one for each model

Comment: No; I don't think it's strange because I've seen it before. In your images I don't see a clear relationship to make any linear fit convincing. Quantile regression fits can jump around more than one expects at first. Prof Koenker is naturally a top authority here.

Comment: Okay thanks for your feedback. Once I add the dither I get a non-zero estimate.

Comment: You need to do that reproducibly, i.e  repeat and see what happens and perhaps report a distribution of slope estimates.

Comment: right, makes sense. I'm using set.seed for reproducible results